# How can i make one slide stays longer than others in owlCarousel

Tags: javascript

```
$(".banner-slider").owlCarousel({
    navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
    pagination: true,
      slideSpeed : 50000,
      singleItem:true,
      autoPlay: true,
      autoPlay : 6000,
  });
```

Comment: Check this : https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/2090

Comment: Hello Asim, it would be useful if you could create a [mcve] so we could see the issue on the question. Read [ask] and complete the [tour] for recommendations on how to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of times ` var delays = [4000,3000,5000,3000];

```
function pageLoad() {
    $(function () {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({
            pauseTime: 50000,
            directionNav: true,
            afterChange: function () { setDelay() },
            afterLoad: function () { setDelay() },
            controlNav: true,
            pauseOnHover: false
        });
    });
}

function setDelay() {
    var currentSlide = $('#slider').data("nivo:vars").currentSlide;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#slider').find('a.nivo-nextNav').click()
    }, delays[currentSlide]);

}`
```

Comment: And owlCarousel?